# Custom cart item image in woocommerce cart block (woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail not working)

Tags: woocommerce

WooCommerce recently switched its default shopping cart page from a shortcode implementation to a blocks-based implementation, and the hook `woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail` no longer seems to work.

Is there a mechanism to change the cart item thumbnail in the WooCommerce cart block?